# AJAX Control Toolkit error after redirect in ASP on Google Chrome v58

Tags: asp.net, google-chrome, ajaxcontroltoolkit

i just want to ask if there is anyone experience this error?

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mBMRz.jpg)

I always encounter this error after I use ajax controls like autocomplete or modalpopup. Then without submitting on update panel but it the fields have values, I redirect it to another page. But, this error only shows up on the latest version of Google Chrome. [See this picture for Google Chrome version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d3tFa.jpg)

I tried updating our Ajax Control Toolkit to the latest version which is 17.1.0, but still encountering the same error. I cannot show more information especially the code. Thank you for understanding. Anyone who experienced or encountered this error? Thank you in advance!

Comment: @aldring try to set ScriptMode property of ScriptManager to Release instead of Debug which is bydefault in Debug

Comment: @Webruster I tried it sir but still no good. Thank you by the way